# Side of house leaking water?

Tags: plumbing, walls, leak

I was walking alongside my house and noticed a wet space near the concrete. I took a close look and saw some deterioration and pipe exposure. The inside is garage wall with this white plumbing thing. What is it? Directly above is the master bath which I figure drains through here.

What are my next steps?

Tear our the drywall and see what's going on in there?

https://imgur.com/a/KKezA6B

Answer (score 1):

White plumbing of this size is almost certainly a drain. I believe you are looking at a clean-out access. It shouldn't leak. Drains shouldn't leak. But the water could just be running down the outside of the drain pipe after leaking elsewhere and possibly moving sideways before running down this pipe. I'm afraid you need to find out where the actual leak is before anything can be done about it; it could be anything between here and the roof vent (assuming there is one). Or the pipe might not be involved at all.